# Having difficulty getting user selection to output from a line in the array

Tags: java, arrays, string, input

I am trying to work on a program that takes user input and based on the state they choose outputs the associated state bird and flower. Currently, if you run it, it will print out every state and the associated information. But I am trying to have it print out just 1 individual line. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StateBirdAndFlower {

    private static String state = new String();
    private static final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static final String[][] fsAndBs = {
        {"Alabama", "Flower: Camelia", "Bird: Northern flicker"},
        {"Alaska", "Flower: Forget-me-not", "Bird: Willow ptarmigan "},
        {"Arizona", "Flower: Saguaro cactus blossom", "Bird: Cactus wren "},
        {"Arkansas", "Flower: Apple blossom", "Bird: Northern mockingbird "},
        {"Califorina", "Flower: Califorina poppy", "Bird: California quail"},
        {"Colorado", "Flower: Rocky Mountian columbine", "Bird: Lark bunting"},
        {"Connecticut", "Flower: Mountain laurel ", "Bird: American robin"},
        {"Delaware", "Flower: Peach blossom", "Bird: Delaware Blue Hen "},
        {"Florida", "Flower: Orange blossom ", "Bird: Northern mockingbird "},
        {"Georgia", "Flower: Cherokee rose ", "Bird: Brown thrasher ", },
        {"Hawaii", "Flower: Hawaiian hibiscus ", "Bird: Nēnē or Hawaiian goose"},
        {"Idaho", "Flower: Syringa, mock orange ", "Bird: Mountain bluebird  "},
        {"Illinois", "Flower: Violet ", "Bird: Northern cardinal "},
        {"Indiana", "Flower: Peony ", "Bird: Northern cardinal "},
        {"Iowa ", "Flower: Wild prairie rose ", "Bird: Eastern goldfinch "},
        {"Kansas", "Flower: Sunflower", "Bird: Western meadowlark"},
        {"Kentucky", "Flower: Goldenrod ", "Bird: Northern cardinal"},
        {"Louisiana", "Flower: Magnolia ",  "Bird: Brown pelican "},
        {"Maine", "Flower: White pine cone and tassel ", "Bird: Black-capped "
            + "chickadee "},
        {"Maryland", "Flower: Black-eyed susan ", "Bird: Baltimore oriole"},
        {"Massachusetts", "Flower: Mayflower ", "Bird: Black-capped chickadee "},
        {"Michigan", "Flower: Apple blossom",  "Bird: American robin "},
        {"Minnesota", "Flower:Pink and white lady's slipper ","Bird: Common loon"},
        {"Mississippi", "Flower: Magnolia", "Bird: Northern mockingbird "},
        {"Missouri", "Flower: Hawthorn", "Bird: Eastern bluebird "},
        {"Montana", "Flower: Bitterroot ", "Bird: Western meadowlark "},
        {"Nebraska", "Flower: Goldenrod", "Bird: Western meadowlark"},
        {"Nevada", "Flower: Sagebrush ", "Bird: Mountain bluebird "},
        {"New Hampshire ", "Flower: Purple lilac ", "Bird: Purple finch "},
        {"New Jersey", "Flower: Violet ", "Bird: Eastern goldfinch "},
        {"New Mexico", "Flower: Yucca flower", "Bird: Roadrunner  "},
        {"New York", "Flower: Rose", "Bird: Eastern bluebird "},
        {"North Carolina", "Flower: Flowering dogwood", "Bird: Northern cardinal "},
        {"North Dakota", "Flower: Wild prairie rose ", "Bird: Western meadowlark "},
        {"Ohio", "Flower: carlet carnation ", "Bird Northern cardinal: "},
        {"Oklahoma", "Flower: Oklahoma rose ",  "Bird: Scissor-tailed flycatcher "},
        {"Oregon", "Flower: Oregon grape ", "Bird: Western meadowlark "},
        {"Pennsylvania", "Flower: Mountain laurel", "Bird: Ruffed grouse"},
        {"Rhode Island", "Flower: Violet", "Bird: Rhode Island Red "},
        {"South Carolina", "Flower: Yellow jessamine ","Bird: Carolina wren", },
        {"South Dakota ", "Flower: Pasque flower ", "Bird: Ring-necked pheasant"},
        {"Tennessee", "Flower: Iris", "Bird: Northern mockingbird ",},
        {"Texas", "Flower: Bluebonnet sp. ", "Bird: Northern mockingbird "},
        {"Utah", "Flower: Sego lily", "Bird: California gull "},
        {"Vermont", "Flower: Red clover ", "Bird: Hermit thrush"},
        {"Virginia", "Flower: American dogwood", "Bird: Northern cardinal"},
        {"Washington", "Flower: Coast rhododendron", "Bird: Willow goldfinch "},
        {"West Virginia", "Flower:Rhododendron", "Bird: Northern cardinal "},
        {"Wisconsin", "Flower: Wood violet ", "Bird: American robin "},
        {"Wyoming", "Flower: Indian paintbrush ", "Bird: Western meadowlark "}};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int rows = 0; rows < fsAndBs.length; rows++) {
            System.out.println("");

                for(int col = 0; col < fsAndBs[col].length; col++) {
                    System.out.println(fsAndBs[rows][col] + " ");

                }
            }



        do {
            System.out.println("Enter a State or None to Exit");
            state = sc.next();




        } while (!state.equalsIgnoreCase("none"));

        if (state.equalsIgnoreCase("none")) {
            System.out.println("goodbye");
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an `String[][]` here is probably not the simplest answer, since you would have to loop through the entire array to get the state you are looking for.

But here is that solution:

```
private String[] getState(String input){
    for(String [] state: fsAndBs){
        if(state[0].equalsIgnoreCase(input){
            return state;
        }
    }
    // return null if input is not a valid state
    return null;
}
```

Then just add `String [] stateValues = getState(state)` to your main.

The more OO solution is as follows (it is a lot more verbose, but gives you State objects which you can pass around and user easily as well as better readability than those horrible two dimensional arrays).

```
     public class StateBirdAndFlower {

         private static class State {

             private final String name;
             private final String bird;
             private final String flower;

             State(String name, String bird, String flower) {
                 this.name = name;
                 this.bird = bird;
                 this.flower = flower;
             }

             public String getName() {
                 return name;
             }

             public String getBird() {
                 return bird;
             }

             public String getFlower() {
                 return flower;
             }
         }

         private static String stateName = new String();
         private static final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         private static Map<String, State> statesMap = new HashMap<String, State>();

         public static void main() {
             setupMap();
             // ... your other code ...

             do{
                 System.out.println("Enter a State or None to Exit");
                 stateName = sc.next();
                 State state = statesMap.get(stateName.toLowerCase());
                 // ... do your thing with the state ...
             } while (!stateName.equalsIgnoreCase("none")); 

             // .. the rest of your code here 
         }

         private static void setupMap() {
             // set up a map entry for each state
             State ala = new State("Alabama","Camelia","Northern flicker");
             statesMap.put(ala.getName().toLowerCase(), ala);
             State alas = new State("Alaska","Forget-me-not","Willow ptarmigan");
             statesMap.put(alas.getName().toLowerCase(), alas);
             // ... etc ...
         }
     }
```

Comment: If you don't mind that would also be most heplful. Again I appreciate this greatly!

Comment: @DavidCline I have updated the answer with a self contained OO solution for you. Also, apologies for the state variable names, I'm not American, so I don't know the three letter abbreviations as well as you guys do.

Comment: I appreciate your help but I am still unable to get it working correctly

Comment: @DavidCline what seems to be the symptoms... we'll get it to work eventually.

Comment: I finally figured out my problem, I really do appreciate the effort and help you provided me! Thank you very much

Comment: @DavidCline That's exactly what SO is all about. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing incorrectly. Thank you everyone for the assistance though

/* File: StateBirdAndFlowerProgram.
 * Author: David Cline
 * Date: February 28,2015
 * Purpose: Take user input and compare it to an array to gather appropriate data to output.
 * User enters none when they wish to exit.
 */
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StateBirdAndFlowerProgram {

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {

      // Begin Scanner for user input later on
      Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

       //Begin array of information
      String[][] states={
                        {"Alabama", "Flower: Camelia", "Bird: Northern flicker"},
                        {"Alaska", "Flower: Forget-me-not", "Bird: Willow ptarmigan "},
                        {"Arizona", "Flower: Saguaro cactus blossom", "Bird: Cactus wren "},
                        {"Arkansas", "Flower: Apple blossom", "Bird: Northern mockingbird "},
                        {"Califorina", "Flower: Califorina poppy", "Bird: California quail"},
                        {"Colorado", "Flower: Rocky Mountian columbine", "Bird: Lark bunting"},
                        {"Connecticut", "Flower: Mountain laurel ", "Bird: American robin"},
                        {"Delaware", "Flower: Peach blossom", "Bird: Delaware Blue Hen "},
                        {"Florida", "Flower: Orange blossom ", "Bird: Northern mockingbird "},
                        {"Georgia", "Flower: Cherokee rose ", "Bird: Brown thrasher ", },
                        {"Hawaii", "Flower: Hawaiian hibiscus ", "Bird: NÄ“nÄ“ or Hawaiian goose"},
                        {"Idaho", "Flower: Syringa, mock orange ", "Bird: Mountain bluebird  "},
                        {"Illinois", "Flower: Violet ", "Bird: Northern cardinal "},
                        {"Indiana", "Flower: Peony ", "Bird: Northern cardinal "},
                        {"Iowa ", "Flower: Wild prairie rose ", "Bird: Eastern goldfinch "},
                        {"Kansas", "Flower: Sunflower", "Bird: Western meadowlark"},
                        {"Kentucky", "Flower: Goldenrod ", "Bird: Northern cardinal"},
                        {"Louisiana", "Flower: Magnolia ",  "Bird: Brown pelican "},
                        {"Maine", "Flower: White pine cone and tassel ", "Bird: Black-capped chickadee "},
                        {"Maryland", "Flower: Black-eyed susan ", "Bird: Baltimore oriole"},
                        {"Massachusetts", "Flower: Mayflower ", "Bird: Black-capped chickadee "},
                        {"Michigan", "Flower: Apple blossom",  "Bird: American robin "},
                        {"Minnesota", "Flower:Pink and white lady's slipper ","Bird: Common loon"},
                        {"Mississippi", "Flower: Magnolia", "Bird: Northern mockingbird "},
                        {"Missouri", "Flower: Hawthorn", "Bird: Eastern bluebird "},
                        {"Montana", "Flower: Bitterroot ", "Bird: Western meadowlark "},
                        {"Nebraska", "Flower: Goldenrod", "Bird: Western meadowlark"},
                        {"Nevada", "Flower: Sagebrush ", "Bird: Mountain bluebird "},
                        {"New Hampshire ", "Flower: Purple lilac ", "Bird: Purple finch "},
                        {"New Jersey", "Flower: Violet ", "Bird: Eastern goldfinch "},
                        {"New Mexico", "Flower: Yucca flower", "Bird: Roadrunner  "},
                        {"New York", "Flower: Rose", "Bird: Eastern bluebird "},
                        {"North Carolina", "Flower: Flowering dogwood", "Bird: Northern cardinal "},
                        {"North Dakota", "Flower: Wild prairie rose ", "Bird: Western meadowlark "},
                        {"Ohio", "Flower: carlet carnation ", "Bird Northern cardinal: "},
                        {"Oklahoma", "Flower: Oklahoma rose ",  "Bird: Scissor-tailed flycatcher "},
                        {"Oregon", "Flower: Oregon grape ", "Bird: Western meadowlark "},
                        {"Pennsylvania", "Flower: Mountain laurel", "Bird: Ruffed grouse"},
                        {"Rhode Island", "Flower: Violet", "Bird: Rhode Island Red "},
                        {"South Carolina", "Flower: Yellow jessamine ","Bird: Carolina wren", },
                        {"South Dakota ", "Flower: Pasque flower ", "Bird: Ring-necked pheasant"},
                        {"Tennessee", "Flower: Iris", "Bird: Northern mockingbird ",},
                        {"Texas", "Flower: Bluebonnet sp. ", "Bird: Northern mockingbird "},
                        {"Utah", "Flower: Sego lily", "Bird: California gull "},
                        {"Vermont", "Flower: Red clover ", "Bird: Hermit thrush"},
                        {"Virginia", "Flower: American dogwood", "Bird: Northern cardinal"},
                        {"Washington", "Flower: Coast rhododendron", "Bird: Willow goldfinch "},
                        {"West Virginia", "Flower:Rhododendron", "Bird: Northern cardinal "},
                        {"Wisconsin", "Flower: Wood violet ", "Bird: American robin "},
                        {"Wyoming", "Flower: Indian paintbrush ", "Bird: Western meadowlark "}};
      // While loop to search through array
      while(true) {

           // Request user input
           System.out.println("Enter a state: ");
           // Capture user input
           String stateName =input.nextLine();
           // exit statement
           if(stateName.equalsIgnoreCase("None"))
                // Exit program
                System.exit(0);

           else {
                // For loop to search through array
                for(int row=0,column=0;row<states.length;row++) {
                     // If statement for matching input string to array data
                     if(states[row][0].equalsIgnoreCase(stateName)) {
                          // Print bird information
                          System.out.println("Bird: " + states[row][column+1]);
                          // Print Flower information
                          System.out.println("Flower: " + states[row][column+2] + "\n");

                     } // end if

                } // end for

           } // end else

      } // end while

 } // end main
```

} // end class